is it centos linux is outdated now for web server?
The CentOS Project announced in December 2020 that it would discontinue CentOS Linux, shifting focus to CentOS Stream. CentOS Linux 8 reached its end of life on December 31, 2021, and CentOS Linux 7 will reach its end of life on June 30, 2024.
Is it Really centos linux is outdated  now for web server? and discontinued

While the question may be considered opinion based, AlmaLinux could be a replacement for CentOS.
About AlmaLinux OS starts with:

AlmaLinux OS is an open-source, community-driven Linux operating system that fills the gap left by the discontinuation of the CentOS Linux stable release. AlmaLinux OS is an Enterprise Linux distro, binary compatible with RHEL®, and guided and built by the community.

And the Who is AlmaLinux For? FAQ says:

Individuals and organizations that require an enterprise-grade linux distribution, without the need for a commercial license agreement. AlmaLinux OS is also a perfect replacement for anyone who has historically relied on the CentOS Linux releases to achieve computing objectives, and for whom CentOS Stream is not the right solution.

In July 2023 AlmaLinux changed from being a 1:1 binary copy of Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) to maintaining ABI compatibility with RHEL. The Future of AlmaLinux is Bright explains that was due to a decision made by Red Hat.

I seem to recall alma and rocky have migration scripts

Yes,
It would probably be best to switch to either the upstream distro (RHEL), an equivalent downstream (e.g Oracle Linux), a similar though less supported downstream or another distro entirely
